# CustomValidator to validate based on other field value is populated in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to validate a field based on other field. If other field is added then only check if its null. If null then show a error message. I found a some sample codes which I used which is working fine for server side validation but I am not getting desired result in client side.

Posting my code here. Please let me know if my approach is correct.

Basically the Email1 field will be required if there is something added in EmailLabel1 else it can be null. What happens at present is that EMail1 field is always returned as required even when emailLabel1 is not entered.

Custom Validator helper:

```
public class RequiredIfOtherFieldIsNotNullAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string _otherField;

    public RequiredIfOtherFieldIsNotNullAttribute(string otherField)
    {
        _otherField = otherField;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var otherField = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_otherField);
        if (otherField == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Unknown property {0}", new[] { _otherField }));
        }

        var otherFieldValue = otherField.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        if (otherFieldValue != null)
        {
            if (value == null || value as string == string.Empty)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new[] { _otherField }));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "requiredif",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherfield", _otherField);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Data annotation in class file:

```
public string EmailLabel1 { get; set; } 

[RequiredIfOtherFieldIsNotNullAttribute("EmailLabel1", ErrorMessage = "Required, since Email Label 1 is filled")]
public string Email1 { get; set; }
```

jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
            'requiredif', ['otherfield'], function (options) {

                var getModelPrefix = function (fieldName) {
                    return fieldName.substr(0, fieldName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                }

                var appendModelPrefix = function (value, prefix) {
                    if (value.indexOf('*.') === 0) {
                        value = value.replace('*.', prefix);
                    }
                    return value;
                }

                var prefix = getModelPrefix(options.element.name),
                    otherfield = options.params.otherfield,
                    fullOtherName = appendModelPrefix(otherfield, prefix),
                    element = $(options.form).find(':input[name="' + fullOtherName + '"]')[0];

                console.log($('#' + otherfield).val());
                options.rules['requiredif'] = options.params;
                if (options.message) {
                   
                    options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
                }
            }
        );

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
            var otherfield = params.otherfield;
            if (value == null && value == '') {
                if ($('#' + otherfield).length > 0 && $('#' + otherfield).val() == "") {
                    $('#' + otherfield).valid();
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }, '');


        $("#Email1").on("change input", function () {
            var validator = $("form:first").validate();
            if ($("#EmailLabel1").val().length == 0) {
                $("#Email1").closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                $("#Email1").closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error-general");
            }
            else { validator.element("#Email1") }
        });

        $("#EmailLabel1").on("change input", function () {
            var validator = $("form:first").validate();
            if ($("#EmailLabel1").val().length > 0) {
                validator.element("#Email1")
            }
            else {
                    $("#Email1").closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                    $("#Email1").closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error-general");
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: I'll  give you an advice for validation approach ,rather than code snippet . I highly recommend you to use fluent validation . It is simpler and cleaner . You dont have to write this much code when using fluent validation. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice but its the existing project we are maintaining, cannot change whats been used already.

Comment: i saw c# and javascript code. i do curious is the javascript relevant? if you could narrow down the problem, that would be nice.